# Adding Class to Div in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Evening all,

I'm trying to add a class to a div I have but it is not working for some reason.

```
$(.example div).addThisClass('example class');
```

Why isn't this working, it works every other time? Has jQuery changed?

Pls help.

Comment: `addClass()` instead `addThisClass()`

Comment: Come on. This is a way too easy thing to ask. Please google it first.

Comment: `it works every other time` unless you created your own method with that name, I can guarantee you it didn't.

Answer (score 1):

There is no method `addThisClass` in jQuery. Use [`addClass`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/):

```
$('div.example').addClass('example class');
```

In Vanilla Javascript, you can use [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList):

```
document.querySelector('div.example').classList.add('example class');
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use jQuery **[addClass()](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/)** function.

```
$(".example div").addClass('example class');
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not `addThisClass`, but `addClass` does it:

```
$('div.example').addClass('example class');
```

Comment: Has this always been the case? I'm sure it used to work.

Comment: @samjohnsonmw No, `addThisClass` was never part of `jQuery`

Answer (score 0):

It's this instead of addThisClass

```
$('div.example').addClass('example class');
```

## getwrecked